# ArcGIS error: Unable to save edits. Raster dataset already exists

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, editing, error, attachments

When I edit my attribute table then try to save edits an error message appears on my screen: "Unable to save edits. Raster dataset already exist." Why does this error message appear?

My table of contents contains one feature class named "Buildings". Buildings have a lot of fields - building name (text), floor number (integer), picture of building (raster), etc. and their capacity about 100gb.

Until Thursday I have edited the attribute table and saved correctly but suddenly I received the above error message on Sunday. I edited some polygons without raster and saved without problem. However I try to edit polygons which contain a raster and then I want to save edits, but the error message does not let me.

Comment: are you editing attribute table of a raster dataset? Do you have write access to the dataset?

Comment: My table of contents contain one feature class that name is "Buildings". Buildngs have a lot of fields building name(text), floor number(integer), picture of building(raster) etc. and their capacity about 100gb. Until thursday ı have edited attribute table and saving correctly but suddenly ı received above error message on sunday. I editing some polygons without raster and saving no problem. However I try to editing polygongs with contain raster and then I want to save edits but error message not to let me.

Comment: try to create a new mxd and then add your featureclass to it and start editing your data. check whether it works?

Comment: I have tried it but anything change. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The only way i found for it to work is to remove the raster data. Save it. Make the changes you want. Save it. Than add the raster data back and save it again. I know this sounds like a hassle but this is the only way i know for it to work. I am sure there is an easier way i just don't know what it is.